# Accessing Wordpress remotely

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, titanium, appcelerator

I was in the process of developing an app in Titanium Mobile. (It's a great way to develop apps btw if you're a web dev).
This app communicates and gets data from a Wordpress server.

(In case you're not familiar with Titanium Mobile, I request you to keep reading the question. Knowledge of that platform is not necessarily important in this case. Thanks)

After a lot of research I finalized on the Wordpress JSON API as a method of communication between the app and the server.
I've got it all up and running successfully and it's great. So far so good.

Now the problem is that my app requirements exceed the functionality provided by the JSON API.

For example, I would like a user to "log in" and maintain a session while using the app. He should be able to edit his Wordpress profile info, etc.

I just want to have an idea how I would be able to best implement this.

One way could be to have a php script running on the server which handles each and every function. Another could be to manually edit the JSON API to add more functionality to it. But that'll take time and I haven't developed a Wordpress plugin before.

Can anyone suggest me a better or easier way of doing the above? I hope I've described what I'm looking for. Apologies if it's too long. I wanted to best explain it.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Wordpress has a XMLRPC interface already, no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Wow thanks! You really saved me from a potential screw-up... I knew about the XMLRPC interface but never had experimented with it. Well, I got it up and running in no time. All's well with the world! Thanks again!

Comment: I added this as an answer, so you can accept it and mark the question as solved. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a XML-RPC interface already, no need to re-invent the wheel.

- [Wordpress XML-RPC Support<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support)
- [Wordpress XML-RPC API<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp)